# Gender information disappears when the page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Variable named `jso` disappears when the page is refreshed. Also, is there any other way to send store information than method?
It will work when the page is refreshed and reopened without using a button.

**view/userProfile.vue**

```
<template>
<div>

<v-list>
  <v-list-item>
  {{userdata['username']}}</v-list-item>
 <v-list-item>  {{userdata['id']}}</v-list-item>
  <v-list-item>  {{userdata['email']}}</v-list-item>
  <v-list-item>  {{userdata['phone_number']}}</v-list-item>
  <v-list-item>  {{userdata['first_name']}} {{userdata['last_name']}}</v-list-item>
<v-list-item >   {{userdata['gender']}}</v-list-item>

 {{userdata['educational_status']}}


</v-list>
<hr>
{{this.profileData.gender}}

{{jso}}  --> variable that disappears on page refresh



</div>
</template>

<script>
```

**Only  jso disappears on refresh page:**

```
  import Vuetify from "vuetify"
  import {UserData} from "../../store/userModule";
  import {JsonChoiceData} from "../../store/choiceStore";
  import jsonDict from "../../jsonFiles/data.json"
  import JsonFile from "../../jsonFiles/jsonfile"


  export default {
    name: "userProfile",

  data(){
    return {
      profileData:{
        username:'',
        first_name:'',
        last_name: '',
        email:'',
        phone_number:'',
        birthday:'',
        gender:'',
        educational_status:'',
        martial_status:'',

      },

    }
  },

  created(){
    this.$store.dispatch('initUserData')
    this.$store.dispatch('inijson')
   
  },

    computed:{
    jso(){
      return this.$store.getters.user
    },


userdata (){

  for(var i in this.$store.getters.getUser){
    return this.$store.getters.getUser[i]
  }
    return this.$store.getters.getUser},


    },

    methods:{
      getjsondata(){
        console.log(this.userdata['gender'] + "methods")
        this.$store.dispatch('getJsonData',this.userdata['gender'])
        console.log(this.userdata['gender'])

      }
    },

    mounted(){
      this.getjsondata()


    }


  }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

**store**

```
import JsonFiles from '../jsonFiles/jsonfile'
import Jsondict from '../jsonFiles/data.json'
import jsonfile from "../jsonFiles/jsonfile";

export  const JsonChoiceData = {

state: {
user: [],


},
 getters: {
 user(state) {
  return state.user
 },
 },


 mutations: {

inijson(state, user) {
  state.user = user
},


getsonData: function (state, userinput) {

  var getJsoncleandata = jsonfile.JsonData(userinput, Jsondict.Gender)


    state.user = getJsoncleandata

    return getJsoncleandata

 }

},

actions: {

inijson(context){
  context.commit('inijson', this.getsonData)

},


getJsonData(context,userinput){

  context.commit('getsonData',userinput)

}

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getsonData` is a mutation and shouldn't be used as payload of another mutation. You are also trying to dispatch `initUserData` action which is not inside your store. I think that you can try to commit `getsonData` mutation inside your `inijson` action.

```js
mutations: {
    ...,
    getsonData: function(state, userinput) {
        const getJsoncleandata = jsonfile.JsonData(userinput, Jsondict.Gender);
        state.user = getJsoncleandata;
    }
    ...
},
actions: {
    inijson(context) {
        context.commit('getsonData', null)
    },
    ...
}
```

Then inside created hook of your component dispach only `inijson` action:

```js
...
created() {
  this.$store.dispatch('inijson')
},
...
```

> If you see strange date make sure that `jsonfile.JsonData(userinput, Jsondict.Gender)` doesn't return a Promise.

Instead of using global `$store` you can also consider to use vuex store mappers. [component binding helpers](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#mapstate)